# Limit to Open Processes

Tags: .net, vb.net, server

I've build a service that monitors a set of Forms programs built using VB .Net Framework 4. This is a multiple instance forms program where the file name gets renamed accordingly. If the forms program isn't running, the process starts the program:

```
Private Sub StartProcess(ByVal CommChannel As String, ByVal status As Integer)
    Dim fileName As String = ServerConfig.OpcToDbFilePath & CommChannel & "\" & GetProcName(CommChannel)
    fileName &= ".exe"
    CopyFiles(fileName, CommChannel)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
            Dim opcProcess As New Process
            Try
                opcProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
                opcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName
                opcProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                opcProcess.Start()
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ...
            End Try
        Else
            ...
    Catch ex As Exception
        ...
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

It works great until after the 28th program starts up. After that, the forms program that I'm trying to start unexpectedly closes.

Am I reaching some sort of limit to how many instances can be opened up? The service and Forms programs are running on Windows Server Datacenter 2012.

Comment: Are you saying that you are opening multiple instances of your services ***or*** many other screen's and you are monitoring with just one service? Also this is very broad (asking for debug help), it could be many things. Without any code to look at we wont be much help; guessing game at this point. Please update your question before it get's voted to be closed out.

Comment: One Service and multiple form applications.

Comment: Ok, have you set breakpoints, implemented any kind of try/catch blocks to trap what is going on? You haven't mentioned what you have tried except the program unexpectedly closes... If that is the case an error is being thrown and you are swallowing it ***or*** the program is handling it...

Comment: I tried debugging with breakpoints, try/catch, and logging exceptions to file. The only thing I get is a log to windows saying that there was an unhandled exception when everything is wrapped in a try/catch.

Comment: I should add that this never happens when I'm debugging. It only happens when the service (running as LocalService)  spins the program up and only when there's more than 28 instances open.

Comment: FYI, those `Process` instances you are creating have a `Dispose` method.  It probably is not the cause of the problem, but it can't hurt to clean that up either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the exception you're getting is happening outside of your try catch loop. This can be caused by initializers etc. To catch all exceptions in a winforms app I do the following:

1. Untick enable application framework in the project page.
2. Add a module with the new startup code. Note: don't initialize member variables in this module until you're inside Main's try catch loop

   ```
   Public Sub Main()
       Try
           AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf HandleFatalException
           AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf HandleFatalException

           Using frm As New MyForm
               Application.Run(frm)
           End Using

       Catch ex As Exception
           HandleFatalException(ex)
       End Try
   End Sub

   Private Sub HandleFatalException(ex As Exception)
       Log.Fatal("Unhandled Exception", ex)
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & "See log file from more details", "Application Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
       Application.Exit()
   End Sub

   Private Sub HandleFatalException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
       HandleFatalException(CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception))
   End Sub

   Private Sub HandleFatalException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
       HandleFatalException(e.Exception)
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Ok, after using FloatingKiwi's suggestion I get this error:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Error creating window handle.

Comment: Check the stack traces and see whether the exception is always in the some spot. Otherwise just take 1 instance of the app and debug it with a profiler (I recommend jetbrains dotMemory) take a look at the handle count for each instance and make sure you're not getting any leaks. Process explorer can also be used to check handle count. See whether 28* the count is anywhere near the Max. There are a lot of articles on reducing handle count further.

Comment: Thanks FloatingKiwi. You're suggestions pointed me in the right direction. It was the Desktop Heap causing the problem.

Comment: I should add that the handles didn't come anywhere near the limit. I also raised the GDI limit to the maximum just to make sure that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit to how many handles and GDI objects as described in:

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/)

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/02/24/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-1/)

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/03/31/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-2/)

These can pose limitations on how many windows/processes you can have open. The handles vary based on architecture and the default maximum count for GDI is 10,000.

There's also the Desktop Heap which was what my problem was:
[Desktop Heap Overview](http://dbmentors.blogspot.com/2011/09/desktop-heap-overview.html)

I modified the third numerical value in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems\Windows" to 3072 (previously 768) and viola! Magic.